# jQuery calculate total amount base on input number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a form that user can pick a number of tickets with `<input type="number">` field, the price is fixed $5/ticket. I want to display the total price dynamically in the readonly field follows.

Questions:

- How to display $5 in the total amount by default?
- If you input 2 tickets it should say $10, and 3 tickets $15, and so on.

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  var $amount_fields = $('#number-tickets'),
      $total_amount = $('#total-amount');
      
  $amount_fields.on('input', function(e) {
    var final_value = 0;
    $amount_fields.each(function() {
      var value = $(this).val();
      if (!isNaN(value) && value > 0) final_value += parseInt(value);
    });
    $total_amount.val(final_value);
  });

});
```

```css
label, span {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <span>Number of tickets @ $5/ticket:</span>
  <input type="number" name="number-of-tickets" value="1" min="1" id="number-tickets" />
</label>
<label>
  <span>Total amount:</span>
  $ <input type="text" name="total-amount" value="" id="total-amount" readonly />
</label>
```

Comment: For your second bullet point, where in your code are you doing the multiplication by 5?

Comment: If you add a variable for price of one ticket, then in the $total_amount.val(final_value * ticket_price);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to multiply the amount by 5 to show the proper total. Note that `parseInt` should be passed a [radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Then to have it display properly upon the page loading use `.trigger('input')`

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var $amount_fields = $('#number-tickets'),
    $total_amount = $('#total-amount');
  $amount_fields.on('input', function(e) {
    var final_value = 0;
    $amount_fields.each(function() {
      var value = $(this).val();
      if (!isNaN(value) && value > 0) final_value += parseInt(value,10) * 5;
    });
    $total_amount.val(final_value);
  }).trigger('input');
});
```

```css
label,
span {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <span>Number of tickets @ $5/ticket:</span>
  <input type="number" name="number-of-tickets" value="1" min="1" id="number-tickets" />
</label>
<label>
  <span>Total amount:</span>
  $
  <input type="text" name="total-amount" value="" id="total-amount" readonly />
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you, `.trigger('input')` is what I need the most.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the part where you multiply by your ticket price.  I placed a comment in the section where this should be taken care of.

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  var $amount_fields = $('#number-tickets'),
      $total_amount = $('#total-amount');
      
  $amount_fields.on('input', function(e) {
    var final_value = 0;
    $amount_fields.each(function() {
      var value = $(this).val();
      if (!isNaN(value) && value > 0) final_value += parseInt(value);
    });
    $total_amount.val(final_value * 5);  // You need to multiply by the ticket price ($5) before setting the field's value.
  });

});
```

```css
label, span {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <span>Number of tickets @ $5/ticket:</span>
  <input type="number" name="number-of-tickets" value="1" min="1" id="number-tickets" />
</label>
<label>
  <span>Total amount:</span>
  $ <input type="text" name="total-amount" value="" id="total-amount" readonly />
</label>
```